# Powershell Script To Reindex WSUS DB and email results

Tags: powershell

Hi I am trying to write a PowerShell script that reindexs the WSUS Database and I am stuck.  So far I have a separate config file that holds the email details of the server, and I think I have got the WSUS reindex working.  However I'm stuck getting the data from the sql query. I have used a [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd939795(v=ws.10).aspx) article as a starting point.

The code I have so far is:

```
$configKey = @{}
Get-Content server.ini | ForEach-Object {
$keys = $_ -split "=" 
$configKey += @{$keys[0]=$keys[1]}
}

cd "c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\"
"Invoke-sqlcmd -I -i"c:\scripts\WSUSDBMaintenance.sql" -S "np:\\.\pipe\MSSQL$MICROSOFT##SSEE\sql\query"

#file backup

$body += '<font size="5"  face="Calibri"Windows Server Reindex Report:</font><br / ><font face="Calibri">'
$body += $Result + "<br>"
"
 Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "PRINT 'Number of indexes to rebuild: ' + cast(@@ROWCOUNT as nvarchar(20)';" -Verbose

 $body += "</div></font>"


 $subject += $configKey.company
#Send Email
Send-MailMessage -From $configKey.from -To $configKey.to -Subject $subject -Body $Body -BodyAsHtml -Smtpserver $configKey.server
```

Comment: When I run the code I get no output. please bare with me David in new to PowerShell

Comment: replace PRINT by select.

Answer (score 0):

a few things jump out at me.

1. "Invoke-sqlcmd -I -i"c:\scripts\WSUSDBMaintenance.sql" -S "np:\.\pipe\MSSQL$MICROSOFT##SSEE\sql\query"

should probably be

Invoke-sqlcmd -I -i "c:\scripts\WSUSDBMaintenance.sql" -S "np:\.\pipe\MSSQL$MICROSOFT##SSEE\sql\query"

1. And you have an extraneous double quote here:
   $body += $Result + "<br>"
   "<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
2. Also, are the tools really in a directory called Binn rather than Bin?

Comment: Hi Mr Paul  , thanks for your input yes they are in a folder called Binn